# Errors installing nginx on Linux- wheezy

Tags: linux, nginx, debian-wheezy

I have a remote server(Linux debian version: 7.8), which is not connected to outside world due to some security issues at my company. For this wheezy os: I see only version available for nginx is : [1.2.1-2.2+wheezy4](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/nginx), But there is no [etag](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#etag) support in this version.

I wanted to upgrade it but there is no higher version available in [wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/nginx), so I downloaded deb file for [1.6.2-5+deb8u1~bpo70+1](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/nginx) for wheezy-backports, uploaded to the server and tried installing it. But I got this error:

```
> sudo dpkg -i nginx-full_1.6.2-5+deb8u1-bpo70+1_amd64.deb

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx-full:
 nginx-full depends on nginx-common (= 1.6.2-5+deb8u1~bpo70+1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing nginx-full (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

So I downloaded deb file for [nginx-common](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/nginx-common) for wheezy-backports, and tried to install it but then I got this error:

```
>sudo dpkg -i nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u1-bpo70+1_all.deb 

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx-common:
 nginx-common depends on init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~); however:
  Package init-system-helpers is not installed.

dpkg: error processing nginx-common (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

I downloaded init-system-helpers_1.34_all.deb, and tried installing it, but:

```
>sudo dpkg -i init-system-helpers_1.34_all.deb

dpkg: regarding init-system-helpers_1.34_all.deb containing init-system-helpers:
 init-system-helpers breaks sysvinit-utils (<< 2.88dsf-59.3~)
  sysvinit-utils (version 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing init-system-helpers_1.34_all.deb (--install):
 installing init-system-helpers would break sysvinit-utils, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 init-system-helpers_1.34_all.deb
```

I am not getting further what to do, Am I doing something wring and these is some better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backports are supposed to be installed not by downloading individual `.deb` files, but by configuring the entire repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. See the [instructions page](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) for details.

The repository is made in such a way that *apt* will not automatically install backports even if they have a later version, so it can be safely configured once and then used via:

```
apt-get install -t wheezy-backports nginx
```

Alternatively, nginx has [its own repository](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html) containing 1.10.0 for Wheezy.